# How can I remove all attributes from an Specific html tag using preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, regex

Consider a php variable which contains a string of text, this text contains some html code, Say if I want to remove attributes from elements like `<br>` but not from `<spam>`

the string contained on the php variable would be something like this:

```
<br id="foo" style="display:none">
<span id="bar">sometext</span>
<br id="bun" />
```

will become this:

```
<br>
<spam id="bar">sometext</span>
<br />
```

Note: I would like to have a regex where I could just change the tag name manually something like:

```
<?php

$str='<br id="foo" style="display:none">
<spam id="bar">sometext</span>
<br id="bun" />';

$tagname = 'br'
$regex = "regexpar1".$tagname."regexpart2";

echo preg_replace($regex,'',$str);
```

Thanks a lot

*EDIT:*
**SOLUTION (thanks to @avinash-raj)**

```
$str='<br id="foo" style="display:none">
<span id="bar">sometext</span>
<br id="bun" />';

$tagname = 'br';

echo preg_replace('~(<'.$tagname.')\b[^>]*?(?=\h*\/?>)~','\1',$str);
```

Comment: I don't see the link between HTML tag removal and regexes. I don't either see PHP or JScript in your post.

Comment: Just added all that thanks for the help, both with the issue and the noob question post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regular expression

You can try this:

```
(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(\/?\s*>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

As you can see in the above picture, you can adapt the `Group 2` to your needs manually. On the picture, the regex is configured to find `br` or `div` tags.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tP6uU1/1)

#### Usage

```
echo preg_replace( '/(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(\/?\s*>)/', '\1\2\4', $str);
```

The `/` is the delimiter of the regular expression here. You can use any another character as long as it is a non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. This is why the `/` is preceded by a `\` in the first regex of this post.

Here are examples with the regex delimited by other delimiters:

```
echo preg_replace( '%(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(/?\s*>)%', '\1\2\4', $str);
echo preg_replace( '+(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(/?\s*>)+', '\1\2\4', $str);
echo preg_replace( ',(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(/?\s*>),', '\1\2\4', $str);
```

[Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) uses a `~` in his post.

Comment: Thanks so much for the speficic answer, is just awesome, it helps a lot to understand the concept, however on php I get a `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '(' in D:\www\test.php on line 2`, when I try to do:  `echo preg_replace('(<)(br|div)([^>]+?)(\/?\s*>)','',$str);`

Comment: @ccrez Please, see the update in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_replace` function.

```
preg_replace('~(<br)\b[^>]*?(?=\h*\/?>)~', '\1', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM5rB7/1)

`\h` matches any kind of horizontal white-space character.

Answer (score 0):

just take id and style in a php variable and do anything with them what you want. here it is (remember make a unique id for each)

```
$id="somthing";
$style="style="display:none"";
```

just echo them at the place of id and style.